# How do you get the max value to be the return?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, max, frequency

I have more or less finished my code, it works with most combinations of letters. It only fails if I enter something like "iiiaa." It returns that 'a' occurs the most, but something like "aaaii" returns that 'a' is also the most. I think the issue has to do with some sort of numerical value because the issue occurs if i list and letter 2 or more times followed by the letter 'a'.
My code currently is:

```
  public static char most_frequent_character(String text)
{
int max_counter = 0;
char max_char = 'a';

for (int i = 1; i < text.length(); i++)
{
  char current = text.charAt(i);
  int counter = count_occurrences(text, current);

  char other_char = text.charAt(i-1);
  if (counter>count_occurrences(text, other_char))
  {
      max_char = current;

  }

}
return max_char;
}
```

count_occurrences returns the amount of times a letter appears in the word

Comment: I take back what I said about it possibly being a value issue. I think it has to do with char max_char starting as 'a'

Comment: An explanation of the problem you are trying to solve would be useful.

Comment: if counter > max_counter and then set the max_counter in the if and you should be done.

Comment: Your logic is wrong. You only compare the number of occurrences of the current char with the number of occurrences of the previous one, instead of comparing it with the number of occurrences of **all** the chars. Use a Map<Character, Integer>, and then find the key that has the largest value in the map.

Comment: @JBNizet beat me too it.  You should loop throught he letters and make a map of the letter and the count, then find the largest in that map.

Answer (score 2):

The `if (counter>count_occurrences(text, other_char))` condition is wrong, since it decides that the current char is the most occuring char if it has more occurences than the previous one. You should compare it to the current max number of occurences. You already have a `max_counter` variable to maintain the current max number of occurences. You should use it. And the loop's index should start at 0.

```
int max_counter = 0;
char max_char = 'a';

for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
{
  char current = text.charAt(i);
  int counter = count_occurrences(text, current);

  if (counter>max_counter)
  {
      max_char = current;
      max_counter = counter; 
  }

}
return max_char;
```

Answer (score 0):

this might help you
in which we take decision on every character through it's index. and iterate for loop until every character has been checked. after that iterate till List size and get max number of occurrence.

```
public static char most_frequent_character(String text)
{
    List<Integer> t = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Character> t2 = new ArrayList<Character>();
    //int max_counter = 0;
    //char max_char = 'a';
    boolean updated = false;
    int indexForChar =0;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        char other_char = text.charAt(i);
        if(t.size()>0)
        for(int j=0;j<t.size();j++)
        {
            if(other_char == t2.get(j))
            {
                t.set(j, t.get(j)+1);
                updated = true;
                indexForChar--;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!updated)
        {
            t.add(1);
            t2.add(indexForChar, other_char);
        }
        updated = false;
        indexForChar++;
    }
    int max = 0;
    int index = 0;
    for(int j=0;j<t.size();j++)
    {
        if(max<t.get(j))
        {
            max = t.get(j);
            index= j;
        }
    }
    return t2.get(index);
}
```